# Can you run a separate venv for each class in python?

Tags: python, python-venv

I am trying to build a class for a group project, and the API I am using does not run consistently unless I setup my venv a certain way. I do not want this to influence or be influenced by my group's project code and the whole class might be scrapped and changed in the future.

With this in mind, I have been looking for a way to build and run a venv just for my Class so that my team can reliably use my code regardless of their venv needs. We might need to run separate venvs for each class in our project depending on our research results moving forward.

I tried running my code in a separate venv that I did not setup and it continued to break until I recreated the same venv I used while developing. I tried looking into resources that would allow me to migrate my venv and into resources that allow me to run just my class in that venv but I cannot seem to find anything to that effect.

I did find out that I can give a list of packages installed and instructions for my team to setup the same venv but I do not want this to be the only environment in effect while they run their code and I do not want to have to deploy with unnecessary packages should I go with a different API.

**Edit**: To clarify my goal is for each class I build to come bundled with its own venv tailor made to run its code independently with zero overlap with other classes/code.

Comment: *"the API I am using does not run consistently unless I setup my venv a certain way"* Can you give more details on this? This might be an XY problem - i.e. you perceive your problem as "I need to have my code run in a separate venv from the rest of the project", but your actual problem might be "I need to resolve the problem which prevents the API from behaving as expected".

Answer (score 0):

A virtual environment is an isolated environment where you can install the dependencies of your project. Each member of your group works on his/her own machine where they create a venv for themselves to work on the same code.

I don't fully understand your question, but I assume you want to implement a new feature (a class as you said) which require different dependencies. Right?

The way to go is that your project group works with version ing, for instance git. You create a new branch, where you can do whatever you want. Add new dependencies, update versions of installed dependencies, etc...This does not influence your project members workspace. As soon as you're ready, you create a pull request, and when your team accept your changes, they can pull/fetch your code, and update the dependencies in their own environment.

So, virtual environments are not shared among team members. It is an isolated machine on your own laptop.

I hope this helps, and I did not misunderstood your question

Comment: What I want is for the master branch to run on any environment and to call my class methods as it needs. When calling any functions in my class, that function would execute in a separate venv that would maintain what my class needs to run properly.

In the future, I may change my mind about this class and build a new one, in that case I want to seamlessly replace that class and its venv with zero impact on their code.

Ultimately, I want each of my classes to come(and leave) with its own venv that's tailor made for it with no overlap with the rest of the project's code.

Comment: It sounds like you should create an API that others can use. Their processes and your process run separately.

Comment: Yes, or create different packages

Comment: I am not sure I know/understand how to do that. Would you mind pointing me to some resources that I can read/watch to learn how to do this?

Comment: You can create a separate project of your class. Then package your project such team members can install it with pip install. Then, if you want to change your class, you simply update your project, and publish a new version which they can install. Check out: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Or with Poetry: https://python-poetry.org/.

Comment: It is not even necessary to publish it on PyPi. You can also easily share the .whl files.

Comment: I looked into it and it seems to be a way to share my code and update it which is convenient for me, but it does not solve the issue of containing and running my class in a separate venv. I want the venv I customized to run my code and to only be used to run my code. Other teammates code should run on whichever environment they choose to run the overall project. Is there a way to do such a thing? From what I found it doesn't seem like you can segregate the running environment of a python project into several environments. I am hoping there is a way.